# Equation incidence diagram in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

There is a new feature of showing the equation incidence diagram in Dymola 2021X, but there are more nonlinear equation systems in the incidence diagram than in the translation log, so I am not sure how to compare these two statistics data.
How should interpret this information?

[image]

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

update at 12.23.2020:
here is the result using Dymola 2021x - Hot fix-1

[image]

Comment: This seems in particular be a problem with some libraries automatically converted from MSL 3.2.3 to MSL 4.0.0, for example ThermoPower. But we have fixed the issue in the next Dymola release.

Comment: Actually, I have set MSL version to 3.2.3 in Dymola 2021X and got the above result. I didn’t use the auto-conversion script, does this mean there is some other issue?

Comment: Anyways, the fix will not be available for another few months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dymola labels block as "Non-linear" when it cannot handle them, you will notice that these additional block are a bit odd as it says "Equation block: Calculations"; and not a non-linear tag.

Comment: Any recommendation material if I wanna know more details of how to solve DAE in Dymola?

Comment: Here is a basic introduction.  This is based on the documentation so follow the links to the original material as well.  https://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/model-translation-and-symbolic-manipulation/

Answer (score 1):

There is now a "hotfix" version of Dymola 2021x that fixes this visualization issue.

Comment: Where could I get this hotfix?

Comment: Where you get the original Dymola 2021x distribution; contact your sales channel if needed. The trial download has not been updated.